# If A is nowhere dense, then its complement X \ A is dense in X.

Tags: general-topology

Let X a topological space. A is nowhere dense in 
 if the interior of the closure of A is empty.
I have to prove that if A is nowhere dense, then its complement X \ A is dense in X.
I tried to prove it,  even looking a similar question but I could not prove it. 
Could anyone give me a valid proof??

Comment: Do the counterpositive: If $X\setminus A$ were not dense, then its complement would contain a non-empty open set. Its complement is $X\setminus(X\setminus A)=A$. So, $A$ would contain a non-empty open set. Since the closure of $A$ contains $A$, then it would also contain that non-empty open set.

Answer (score 3):

Let suppose that $X \setminus A$ is not dense in $X$. Then there exists a non-empty open set of $X$, that does not intersect $X \setminus A$. In other words, there exists a non-empty open set contained in $A$. This open set is then also contained in the closure of $A$, hence the interior of the closure of $A$ is non empty.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is nowhere dense, then $int(\bar{A})=\emptyset$. This means that it contains no (non-empty) open sets. Let $U\subset X$ be an open set. Since $A$ is nowhere dense, then $U$ is not a subset of $A$, which means - $U\cap A^c\neq\emptyset$. This means that $A^c$ meets any open set, and it is therefore dense in $X$.